# Treat different widgets as the same so not to rebuild the element tree

Tags: flutter

Here is my dart pad example of my problem: https://dartpad.dev/46edc2b00fe11eac17c8a0a7dfa19e15

I have created some encapsulate widgets, `Counter1` and `Counter2`. They both have the same widget tree structure with only the leaves changing. When I replace `Counter1` with `Counter2` it rebuilds all the elements rather than just update them.

Is there a way to tell Flutter, these widgets are really the same thing and you don't need to create a new Element just update your reference?

It seems inefficient to recreate the elements when only the top encapsulating widget is changing.

**Update**: The general direction I am thinking of accomplishing this is by create a class that extends `StatelessWidget` and then does something to say they're the same thing.

Comment: You're working against the framwork this way.  What is your particular need for this?

Comment: I have a series of screens that are laid out exactly the same but a few of the leaves change, sort of like fragments in Android. Each fragment would then update a portion of a model.

Comment: Why not use the same exact widgets at the top then, and pass various data to the leaves that change?

Comment: Because some of the leaves change, as in become different widgets.

Comment: `MyHomePage` isn't rebuilding only when the `Counter1` and `Counter2` Widgets are changed. It's rebuilt every time the `_counter` variable is updated.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I think I understand what you mean. I'll have to try some things. Thanks for letting me know it goes against the framework.